# The Gimbal BLE option FYXHighAccuracyLocation is an undeclared identifier

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to set the option FYXHighAccuracyLocation, but it can't find the method for some reason. I've imported

```
#import <FYX/FYXVisitManager.h>
#import <FYX/FYXTransmitter.h>
#import <FYX/FYX.h>
```

with the standard code

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[options setObject:[NSString stringWithString:FYXHighAccuracyLocation] forKey:FYXLocationModeKey];
[FYX enableLocationUpdatesWithOptions:options];
```

which is placed right after I set the FYX AppId.

Also, what is the difference between low energy locating, and high accuracy locating?

Answer (score 0):

You must do it like this way,

1. `[FYX disableLocationUpdates];`
2. Set your FYX AppID
3. `[FYX startService:selfdelegate];`
4. Then when FYX services are started successfully, for getting whether services are started or not you have to use FYX delegate methods(`- (void)serviceStarted`,`- (void)startServiceFailed:(NSError *)error`). Then in `- (void)serviceStarted` place your code.

For your second questions regarding difference, you can look over [this gimbal document guide](https://gimbal.com/doc/proximity/ios.html#disable_location).